# How to change colors in an android app?

Tags: java, android

I want to change colors in my options menu for color blind people, I was thinking of having two strings.xml files and switch between them on button press. What is the proper way of changing colors of `ImageButton` that has colors declared in strings.xml ?

```
final Switch colorsChange= (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_colors);
    colorsChange.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                // Color blind friendly colors here

            } else {
                // Normal RGB colors here
                getResources().getColor(R.color.defaultColors);
            }
        }
    });
```

I want to carry these settings across all activities if possible

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: posted. I want to have two variations of the colors in the app

Comment: `if (isChecked) {
                // Color blind friendly colors here
ImageButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(getString(R.string.red))
            } else {
                // Normal RGB colors here
                getResources().getColor(R.color.defaultColors);
            }`

Comment: but that only works in one activity? I need to have it across all activities

Answer (score 0):

button.setColor(Color.RED);
or you can using button.setColor(code color);

Answer (score 0):

You should declare colors in colors.xml

But still,
In string.xml you should declare `<string name="red">#ff0000</string>`

```
ImageButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(getString(R.string.red));//if using string.xml
or
ImageButton.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.red));//if using colors.xml
```

Or, alternatively:

```
ImageButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); // From android.graphics.Color
```

Or, for more pro skills:

```
ImageButton.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000); // 0xAARRGGBB
```

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should define color in color.xml (in "values" directory)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="color_name">#e6e6e6</color>
</resources>
```

and reference to it:

1. In xml file:

   @color/color_name
2. In Java class:

   getResources().getColor(R.color.color_name);

Answer (score 0):

- Add colors you want into your resources
- Give action to your button using `android:onClick="methodName"`
- In your java method get the color by using `getResources().getColor(R.color.idname);`

Comment: thanks but doesnt that only give one variation? I need to have two and switch between them if user selects the option

Comment: You can add a variable in your method which will take a user input as a value